# How to use Wi-Fi Direct (P2P) on Android 3.x devices?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Android developer documentation states (for example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) that Wi-Fi P2P is available since API level 14, i.e. on Android 4.x devices.

However, a few days ago I found a device, Samsung P6800 Galaxy Tab, which runs on Android 3.2 and has full support (in the system options, i.e. not via a custom app) for Wi-Fi Direct! (as seen for example here: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_p6800_galaxy_tab_7_7-4136.php but I did check it personally, too)

So I'm wondering how is this possible, is there a way how to use this API/functionality even in earlier versions?

Comment: It seems Samsung added Wifi Direct to a few of their pre-ICS devices, even on some phones running 2.3. Interested to get hints too.

Comment: Even 2.3? Wow. I'd love to know how to check for that kind of functionality, obviously you can't use the manifest for it.